# How can I fix "blurry/bold" text after CSS transition on transform property?

Tags: css, css-transitions

On my website I have this example of "blurry/bold/glitchy" text that appears after css transition occurs on translateY property.

[See screenshot (top: how it should be / bottom: how it actually looks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9GJd.png)

Here it is live (see as you scroll down): http://louisamiot.com/project/this-is-why

This definitely sounds like a text rendering issue on Webkit because some characters appear bolder than other and everything is fixed when you resize the windows.

I tried several fixes such as -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; and all the common CSS tricks such as translate3D translateZ(0) scale(1.0) and backface-visibility: hidden; but none of them worked.

Any idea ? :)

Thanks a lot to the community.

Comment: Not sure how to fix this using css transitions, but if its helpful to you, I've realized that sometime when you do `scaling` transform transitions, you get some sizes with decimals (100.5px). When this happens in chrome, you see the blurriness. In my case, I wrote some js to remove the decimals. If you find a better way, just let me know...